# Multiple API calls with Promise.all and dispatch an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, es6-promise

I want to call multiple API's and store each response data in an object then I want to dispatch this response object but I'm getting undefined.

Below is the code I tried. May I know where I'm doing wrong?

```
/* COMPONENT.JSX */
componentDidMount() {
  callApis(this.props.products, this.props.profileId);
}

/* API.JS */
const getContactDetails = (http, profileId) => 
 (http.get(`https://www.fakeurl.com/${profileId}/contact`));

const getProductDetails = (http, profileId) => 
  (http.get(`https://www.fakeurl.com/${profileId}/product`));

const callApis = (products, profileId) => (dispatch) => {

  const payload = new Map();

  products.forEach((product) => {

  const apis = [getContactDetails, getProductDetails];

  apis.map(api => api(http, profileId));

  Promise.all(apis)
      .then((response) => {
          const apiData = {
              contactData: getParsedContactData(response[0]),
              productData: getParsedProductData(response[1])
          };
          if (payload.get(product.token)) {
              payload.get(companion.token).push(apiData);
          } else {
              payload.set(product.token, [apiData]);
          }
      })
      .catch(err => {
          throw ('An error occurred ', err);
      });
   });
   dispatch({ type: FETCH_API_DATA, payload: payload });
}
```

I expect the dispatch will be called after all API's were resolved, get parsed, and map into the payload object then it should dispatch.

Comment: `apis.map(api => api(http, profileId));` you're discarding the result ... map returns a new Array ... `Promise.all(apis.map(api => api(http, profileId))). then` will do what you want

Comment: you're also calling `dispatch(...);` before `payload` will have anything in it - because of the asynchronous nature of the code you are dealing with

Comment: 1) Yes! map returns an array in that I see the response of the API. 
2) Where do I need to call the dispatch then?

Comment: you need to call dispatch after ALL promises have resolved

Comment: You mean I need to dispatch in `then` block?

Comment: I've added an answer - hopefully it will work

Comment: Let me try this!

Comment: What I don't understand is how calling `callApis(this.props.products, this.props.profileId);`, which returns a function `(dispatch) => { ... }` ever calls this function that is returned

Answer (score 1):

Array.map returns a new Array, which you are discarding

you're calling dispatch before any of the asynchronous code has run

A few minor changes are required

```
/* API.JS */
const getContactDetails = (http, profileId) => http.get(`https://www.fakeurl.com/${profileId}/contact`);

const getProductDetails = (http, profileId) => http.get(`https://www.fakeurl.com/${profileId}/product`);

const callApis = (products, profileId) => (dispatch) => {
    const payload = new Map();
    // *** 1
    const outerPromises = products.map((product) => {

        const apis = [getContactDetails, getProductDetails];
        // *** 2
        const promises = apis.map(api => api(http, profileId));

        // *** 3
        return Promise.all(promises)
        .then((response) => {
            const apiData = {
                contactData: getParsedContactData(response[0]),
                productData: getParsedProductData(response[1])
            };
            if (payload.get(product.token)) {
                payload.get(companion.token).push(apiData);
            } else {
                payload.set(product.token, [apiData]);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw ('An error occurred ', err);
        });
    }));
    // *** 4
    Promise.all(outerPromises)
    .then(() => dispatch({
            type: FETCH_API_DATA,
            payload: payload
        })
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

1. rather than procucts.forEach, use products.map
2. capture the promises in apis.map to use in `Promise.all`
3. `return Promise.all` so the outer Promises can be waited for
4. Promise.all on the outer promises, to wait for everything to complete.

Comment: this solution is not working. Before Step 3 is resolved Step 4 is getting executed.

Comment: odd, so `outerPromises` isn't an array of pending promises? It's actually calling dispatch too early still? or is there perhaps an error? I've added a .catch to the last Promise.all

Answer (score -2):

```
const callApis = (products, profileId) => async (dispatch) => { // use async function
  const payload = new Map();
  for (const product of products) {
    const apis = [getContactDetails, getProductDetails];

    apis.map(api => api(http, profileId));

    await Promise.all(apis)  // await all promise done
      .then((response) => {
        const apiData = {
          contactData: getParsedContactData(response[0]),
          productData: getParsedProductData(response[1])
        };
        if (payload.get(product.token)) {
          payload.get(companion.token).push(apiData);
        } else {
          payload.set(product.token, [apiData]);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw ('An error occurred ', err);
      });
  }
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_API_DATA, payload: payload }); // dispatch will be executed when all promise done
}
```

Comment: I'm not using async or await.